# problems with pointers to struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have typical structure (ECU_t) which has members that considered to be pointer to struct. now i want to make ECU_DoTask(). please help me

```
typedef enum
{
  NORMAL,
  WARNING,
}WATER_TEMP;

typedef struct
{
  WATER_TEMP water_temp;
  uint16_t speed;
  // ... other members
}Engine_t;

typedef struct
{
  Engine_t* engine;
  ABS_t*  abs;
  // ... other members
}ECU_t;

void ECU_DoTask(ECU_t* output)
{
  output->(engine->water_temp) = NORMAL; 
  // ??? it seems to be illegal command. 
  // how can i access to water_temp
}
```

Comment: Remove the brackets around your call: `output->engine->water_temp = NORMAL`

Comment: if `water_temp = 2`. `output->(engine->water_temp)` gets evaluated as `output->2`, simply makes no sense, even if you could use a number like that as an offset in struct memory, it would still make no sense and cause more segfaults than you can imagine based on your struct size and water temperature :) Use parentheses where you need them.

Answer (score 1):

engine is a member of output and water_temp is a member of engine.

So you can do either:

```
(output->engine)->water_temp = NORMAL
```

OR

```
output->engine->water_temp = NORMAL
```

as -> is left precedence operator.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
output->engine->water_temp = NORMAL;
```

`output` is a pointer to an `ECU_t`, which makes `output->engine` a pointer to an `Engine_t` and then `output->engine->water_temp` be its desired member (as an Lvalue), to which we can assign the value `NORMAL`

---

Note that `output->(engine->water_temp)` makes no sense here because according to the parentheses, you'd have to first evaluate `engine->water_temp`, but `engine` is not defined. And even after that, you'd try to access a member of `*output` that is not given by its name, but rather by the result of evaluating `engine->water_temp`.